# How to close a pop-up window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link in my pop-up window that is supposed to close the pop-up window and show something else on the original page.  The .show() is working but its not closing the window, it just removes everything inside of it (leaving it completely white and blank).

```
$('a', w.document).click(function () {
    w.document.close();
    $('#callScript').show();                
});
```

How do I close the pop-up window?

Comment: I think you're looking for `window.close()`, not `w.document.close()`.

Comment: It was w.window.close() actually because in my code earlier I had written var w = window.open('', '_blank', 'width = 500, height = 500');
Thanks for the inspiration though!

Comment: If that's the case, then you would call `w.close()`.

Comment: use this   $('#callScript').hide();//hide will close

Answer (score 0):

If `w` is the handle to your popup window:

```
$('a', w.document).click(function () {
    w.close();
    $('#callScript').show();                
});
```